# Web scraping - noob

Tags: curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract data from the https://www.scimagojr.com website regarding specific journals. Tryed using curl to extract data using each journal ID.

Example:

Created a curl in a txt named data.txt

```
Curl 'https://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=24589&tip=sid&clean=0'
```

The ID for Annales Zoologici Fennici Journal is 24589, but I changed it in the url to $1 to enable the use of others ID in order to collect data easier

```
Curl 'https://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=$1&tip=sid&clean=0'
```

I tried using

```
./data.txt 24589
```

but it doesn't give information about the journal

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not interpolated within single quotes. Change to double quotes:

```
curl "https://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=$1&tip=sid&clean=0"
```